# Storing image after camera click in my app stores blur image

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-camera-intent

I am asking user to click image from my app and then that image gets stored in local storage and from there to the server ,but the problem is the image which is stored is blurred.

```
public void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap, int i)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, bytes);
    File directory  = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"my_directory");
    if(!directory.exists())
    {
        directory.mkdirs();
    }
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"my_directory");
    try{
        f.createNewFile();
        //write the bytes in file
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the code i am using to save image and this is the OnActivityResult from where the bitmap is generated.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0)
    {
        if(data!=null)
        {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            iv_upload.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

            saveImage(thumbnail,(int)System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Refer this https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath

Comment: You are saving the returned thumbnail instead of the full-size image

Comment: thumbnail gives me the bitmap from where will i get the full size image

Comment: You have to pass the _output file uri_ to the image capture intent like `takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);` Refer the link provided in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason for compressing the image as done in your code?

The Android Camera application encodes the photo in the return Intent delivered to onActivityResult() as a small Bitmap in the extras, under the key "data". The following code retrieves this image and displays it in an ImageView.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

Have you made these changes in Manifest File, Please check

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: i need to store the image for uploading the image to the server

Comment: so compress it after you have retrieved it

Answer (score 0):

You are compressiong your original image here:

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, bytes);
```

Quality Accepts 0 - 100

0 = MAX Compression (Least Quality which is suitable for Small images)

100 = Least Compression (MAX Quality which is suitable for Big images)

So try to change the value of 100 and check the quality.

Comment: Have tried changing the values 100 gives the better images in respect to others

Comment: It might be issue with your device camera. you need to check with your camera settings or need to test with different device.

Comment: Tested with almost 4-5 devices but the result is same